# Python Flask socketio korean letter

Tags: python, encoding, flask

I'm practicing a chat program with Flask socket io.

But, I have problem about sending/receiving korean-letter message.

When I send korean-letter, flask app returns '400 bad gateway' error and server side python code cannot receive any JSON data.

I also checked flask_socketio/init.py. but it cannot receive any data and result to same error.

Below is Flask code and PIP list.

Please advice my problem. thanks.

client .html

```
$('form#broadcast').submit(function(event) {
    socket.emit('my broadcast event', {data: $('#broadcast_data').val()});
    $("#broadcast_data").val('');
    $("#broadcast_data").focus();
    return false;
});
```

server .py

```
@socketio.on('my broadcast event', namespace='/test')
    def test_broadcast_message(message):
        session['receive_count'] = session.get('receive_count', 0) + 1
        emit('my response', {'data': message['data'], 'count': session['receive_count'], 'time':strftime("%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 'sid':request.sid},
             broadcast=True)
```

pip list

```
apt-xapian-index (0.45) 
chardet (2.0.1)
dict (0.0.4)
distribute (0.6.49)
Flask (0.10.1)
Flask-SocketIO (2.2)
greenlet (0.4.9)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.8)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
mercurial (2.8.2)
pip (8.1.0)
python-apt (0.9.3.5ubuntu1)
python-debian (0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2)
python-engineio (0.9.0)  
python-socketio (1.1)
request (0.0.2)
requests (2.2.1)
setuptools (0.6rc11)
six (1.10.0)
ssh-import-id (3.21)
urllib3 (1.7.1)
Werkzeug (0.11.4)
```

flask_socketio / **init**.py

```
skip_sid = flask.request.sid \
    if not kwargs.get('include_self', True) else None
self.server.emit(event, *args, namespace=kwargs.get('namespace', '/'),
                     room=kwargs.get('room'), skip_sid=skip_sid,
                     callback=kwargs.get('callback'))
```

Comment: Have you checked an error log?

Comment: Looks like classical unicode problem. Try to run this application on python3 or use appropriate encoding.

Comment: There's any no log contents, and also no response.@Andrew

Comment: I solved the problem by installing 'eventlet'. 
Thanks for advising